# ggplot, dplyr etc in Windows without rlang.dll?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

In R for Windows and the tidyverse what does rlang.dll do and can I do without it if I install and load libraries such as dyplyr, magrittr and ggplot2 separately?

Comment: The rlang.dll file has compiled code from the {rlang} package. It powers much of the tidyverse's non standard evaluation, so I can't imagine running those libraries without rlang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file rlang.dll is a binary file that contains compiled C code that rlang calls to do some of its work. Since {dplyr} and {ggplot2} both import functions from rlang, this makes rlang a hard dependency of both packages, meaning that these packages can't run without it. If you specifically try to install {ggplot2} and {dplyr} without their hard dependencies, they won't run.

As a concrete example, the first line of the [source code](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/cd851f4245d624e6e24b6f6e2ed025a60ae727d0/R/mutate.R#L178) for the data frame method of dplyr's `mutate` function contains this line:

```r
  keep <- arg_match(.keep)
```

Where `arg_match` is imported from rlang. The [source code](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/blob/4f7da19d432f88d220ca062917929e51473fc5ed/R/arg.R#L31) for `arg_match`
includes a call to the *non-exported* rlang function `arg_match0`, which you can see in the r console by doing:

```r
rlang:::arg_match0
#> function (arg, values, arg_nm = as_label(substitute(arg))) 
#> {
#>     .External(rlang_ext_arg_match0, arg, values, environment())
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x00000258f4d35bd0>
#> <environment: namespace:rlang>
```

This `.External` call indicates that the arguments are being passed to a compiled C function registered in rlang.dll.

So without the rlang dll, there is no `arg_match0`, so no `arg_match`, and therefore no `mutate`. It's difficult to imagine using {dplyr} without `mutate`. And of course, this is just one example.